How do I monitor Windows Scheduled Task for failure through console c#?
My requirement is
For a specific Task, I need to get these details:
1.Last started Datetime and Last Completed Datetime
2.Errors details if any within this instance.
3.Events details.
This code I have written is for diagnosing and monitoring a specific Windows Scheduled Task for failure events and logging them in a C# console application. Unable to achieve the expected output.
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Task = Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task;

namespace TaskSchedule
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Specify the name of the task you want to monitor
            string taskName = "NeverEndingTask";

            // Connect to the Task Scheduler
            using (TaskService taskService = new TaskService())
            {
                // Get the specified task
                Task task = taskService.GetTask(taskName);

                // Check if the task exists
                if (task != null)
                {
                    // Check if task has run recently
                    if (task.LastRunTime != DateTime.MinValue)
                    {
                        // Check if task failed in its last run
                        if (task.LastTaskResult != 0)
                        {
                            // Log the failure
                            Console.WriteLine($"Task '{task.Name}' failed in its last run.");
                            Console.WriteLine($"Last Run Time: {task.LastRunTime}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"Error Message: {task.LastTaskResult}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Log success if the task ran successfully
                            Console.WriteLine($"Task '{task.Name}' ran successfully in its last run.");
                            Console.WriteLine($"Last Run Time: {task.LastRunTime}");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Log if the task hasn't run yet
                        Console.WriteLine($"Task '{task.Name}' has not run yet.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Log if the specified task does not exist
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task '{taskName}' not found.");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}


This is basically a single line of Powershell Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "SomeTask"

But what about failed events? and how do I capture that in c# console
